# How to configure redirect on OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt

Below is uci config and rules that it produces:

```
uci add firewall redirect
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].target=DNAT
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].proto=tcp   
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].src=wan
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].src_dport=80
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest=lan
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest_port=80
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest_ip=10.0.0.10
uci commit firewall
<reboot>
```

```
iptables -t nat -A zone_wan_prerouting -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:80
iptables -t nat -D zone_lan_prerouting -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -d <external_ip_of_router> -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:80
iptables -t nat -A zone_lan_prerouting -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -d <external_ip_of_router> -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.10:80
iptables -t nat -D zone_lan_postrouting -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -d 10.0.0.10 -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A zone_lan_postrouting -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -d 10.0.0.10 -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
```

But it does not work.

(To get the iptables commands, I used `fw3 -4 print` before and after `uci` config, and then `diff`.)

Redirect starts working only when I manually (first purging the uci config) enter rules #1 and #5 from the above list, with `-s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0` removed from rule #5.

But the following uci config works:

```
uci add firewall redirect
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].target=DNAT
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].proto=tcp
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].src=wan
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].src_dport=5000
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest=lan
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest_port=22
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest_ip=10.0.0.2
uci commit firewall
```

How can this be explained?